# Share configuration file at CakePHP between Config files (routles.php, mail.php...)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I have a site running in localhost as a development environment and in a server for production.

There are some differences in some configuration files between both and I every time I have to update the changes in the server I have to be careful not to overwrite some files which are different.

I would like to be able to simplify this process by creating just one single file with the correct configuration for each environment.

I need to read that file currently in this Config files:

- app/Config/email.php
- app/Config/routes.php

And ideally, if possible in:

- app/Vendor/Vendor_name/vendor_file.php

Is it possible somehow?

I have tried to use Configure::read and Configure::write but it seems it can not be done inside email settings such as `public $smtp` or in the routes file.

Thaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routes file is simply a php file with calls to the router. You could very simply split it up into multiple files and load them yourself:

```
app/Config/
  routes.php
  routes_dev.php
  routes_production.php
```

`routes.php` would then load the proper routes file.

```
<?php
if ($env == 'dev') {
  include 'routes_dev.php';
} else {
  include 'routes_production.php';
}
```

The email config is also just a php file. You could write a function to set the proper default config based on the environment.

```
class EmailConfig {

  public function __construct() {
    if ($env == 'dev') {
      $this->default = $this->dev;
    }
  }

  public $default = array(
      'host' => 'mail.example.com',
      'transport' => 'Smtp'
  );

  public $dev = array(
      'host' => 'mail2.example.com',
      'transport' => 'Smtp'
  );

}
```

As for vendor files, that's a case by case basis.

If you have a deployment system, it might be better to actually have separate files for each environment (maybe even a full config directory) and rename them after the deployment build is complete, making Cake and your code none the wiser.

Comment: Thanks! I did the same for the email.php and the routes.php file. Only that in the routes ones i dont have a constructor. I read a variable with `Configure::read()` and used it in a condition as you posted. 

Any solution for the vendor library?

Comment: Yeah, routes isn't a class like EmailConfig is. The vendor one is tricky because a lot depends where you're loading their config. Maybe outline how it works a bit more in your question.

Comment: In this case the Vendor I use only has one class.

Comment: Is the configuration within that class? Is anything else? Where is it loaded? Do you load it or does the vendor (and do they allow dependency injection of any sort)?

Comment: I call it like this after importing the vendor file: `$myClass = new vendorClass();` There's nothing else to configure.

Comment: If there's nothing to configure, then what's the difference between the class in production vs. development?

Comment: Oh no no :) There's something. Just the value of a global variable in the class :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22771/discussion-between-jeremyharris-and-steve)

Comment: @Steve I jumped back in chat

Answer (score 0):

The way I used to handle this situation was to add environment variables to the apache virtualhost configuration.

```
SetEnv cake_apps_path /var/www/apps/
SetEnv cake_libs_path /var/www/libs/
```

This allowed me to then pull $_SERVER['cake_apps_path'] and $_SERVER['cake_libs_path']. Then each developer can set his own variables in his own virtualhost config, and you add that to the server's virtualhost config, and you're done. Each developer can have their own pathing.